# Match a specific element in XML via XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML message, which I am trying to go through via an XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map>
      <array key="results">
         <map>
            <string key="id">5b33c2e8-8ab2-4314-82bf-e41a007c076f</string>
            <string key="profileId">0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22</string>
         </map>
      </array>
      <map key="_embedded">
         <array key="individuals">
            <map>
               <string key="id">0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22</string>
               <string key="name">John</number>
            </map>
         </array>
      </map>
      <map key="paging">
         <number key="pageNumber">1</number>
         <number key="pageSize">10</number>
         <number key="totalCount">4</number>
      </map>
   </map>
</array>
```

My code is like the following:

```
 <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
            <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml">
                <array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/fn:array/fn:map/fn:array[@key = 'results']/*">
                        <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                         <xsl:variable name="profileId">
                            <xsl:value-of select="*[@key = 'profileId']"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:if test="*[@key = 'id'] != ''">
                                <string key="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="*[@key = 'id']"/>
                                </string>
                            </xsl:if>
                           <xsl:for-each select="../fn:map[@key = '_embeded']/fn:array[@key = 'individuals'][@id=$profileId]/*">
                                <array key="profiles">
                                <string key="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="fn:map/*[@key = 'id']"/>
                                </string>  
                                </array>
                            </xsl:for-each>  
                        </map>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </array>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml, map {'indent': true()})"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

What I want to do is map the individuals/id with the results/profileId, but apparently the way I am matching the individuals is not correct.

I would need some help with matching correctly.

Comment: Please explain what "What I want to do is map the individuals/id with the results/profileId" means in terms of wanted result and what " but apparently the way I am matching the individuals is not correct" means in terms of the result you currently get. In general for cross-references in XML you can use a key declaration  and the `key` function, thus if there is a relation between `<string key="profileId">0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22</string>` and `<string key="id">0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22</string>` then using a key can help. But it is not clear which result you need.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I think at this point the most important for me is to correctly match the "individuals" array, could you please check my XPATH and see if it's correct

Comment: Well, if the input has `_embedded` and your code has `_embeded` then spelling differences alone will make any selection fail. And I guess you need to go one level further up with `../..`.

Comment: Match it to what? Please show the expected result and explain the logic required to get it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, that's amazing, thank you so much, I didn't see the typo

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I would like to filter through all profiles that have a specific id, I tried this but it doesn't work: ````<xsl:for-each select="../fn:map[@key = '_embeded']/fn:array[@key = 'individuals'][@id=$profileId]/*">````

Comment: Please edit your question to show minimal but complete code samples. It doesn't make sense to show a snippet in a comment using a variable reference like `$profileId` without having shown any code where you declare the variable and which value you bind to it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I did that, thank you.

Comment: You are still carrying that spelling difference around. Apart from that, the path `fn:array[@key = 'individuals'][@id=$profileId]` doesn't seem to make sense as that `array` element `<array key="individuals">` doesn't have any `id` attribute at all you could compare. It is still not clear which result you want, in terms of XPath selection you seem to want to select an element deeper in the tree or start looking into keys.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, sorry I am new to this, but the ````individuals```` array has a ````<string key="id"> ````, basically I want to select values only if the ````id```` within the array has the value equal to ````profileId````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment

> the `individuals` array has a `<string key="id">` , basically I want to
>   select values only if the `id` within the array has the value equal to
>   `profileId`

you might want to select `fn:array[@key = 'individuals'][.//fn:string[@id = $profileId]]`, that is, an `array` having a descendant `string` with the matching `id`.

It is hard to give a more complete example as the input for instance has `<string key="name">John</number>` which is not well-formed.

As in previous questions, I think moving to template based matching instead of nested for-eachs in a single template would make the code more managable and easier to structure, read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I tried the snippet you provided and it is not filtering..

Comment: Well, you have only that one array and there is a descendant with a matching id so that subexpression should be fine for selection, not sure what you want to "filter" as you have only one such array. As for the rest, I am afraid with an input that is not well-formed, still no indication of that the output is supposed to look like, no explanation of what kind of input/output mapping you want to achieve and a spelling difference not being corrected it is hard to tell where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I figured out what I was doing, you helped a lot!